# Output for a symmetric multiprocessing system

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, race-condition

Consider this code:

```
int x; //declared globally

for( int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
           x++;

printf("%d",x);
```

This is the core logic of the program, ignore the syntactic stuff to create threads, etc.

Now, I have created two threads and the program exhibits race condition when it's run (obviously!).

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the entire for loop is run in one go for a thread and only after that the second thread is run (Assume a uniprocessor system). So the ideal expected output is 1 million for 1st thread and 2 million for 2nd question. (Although which thread prints 2 million is depending on the CPU scheduler)

**My 1st question:** According to the definition of race condition, can the fact that the 1st output and 2nd output is jumbled every time I run the program be considered as race condition? Why?

**2nd question:** Consider a multi-processing system, that runs the for loop simultaneously 1 million times in both the threads. What would be the expected output ideally? Why?

Comment: First, "jumped" output cannot be attributed to anything having to do with that loop.  Second, and due precisely to the very race condition you already announced as known, I expect *nothing* with any predictability whatsoever even if the output wasn't "jumbled". So I'm not sure what the point of the question is. You have already identified this as a race-conditional festival, and we can only assume you know what that is, so what exactly is the *problem* ?

Comment: Race conditions are hard to demonstrate even with proper progrms. I see that some random output is printing most of the times (this can be considered race condition). But other times (rarely), the program is printing `x=1000000` and `x=2000000` (but not in the same order everytime). So my question is, when the program is printing these ideal values, is it demonstrating race condition? The ambiguity is that although the values are right, order is wrong

Comment: It's hard to predict what will happen due to race condition, it can't be determine in advance. It's better you create, test the code and then come up with a question, why that happened, rather predict output for you and explain.

Comment: I'm not asking for the actual output. What would it be ideally? Consider that each micro instruction is in-step with each other in both the processors. Now what would be the output?

Comment: Yes. the output should have been `x=1000000` first and then x=`2000000` right? That's jumbling sometimes

Comment: Not necessarily. When one loop finishes (but before it calls printf) the other loop can still be incrementing `x` so I could see  one of them not being exactly 1,000,000 or 2,000,000 . I would expect the last thread to finish should get the right number though.  In essence after one of your loops finishes there is a small window before printf where the other thread could have incremented `x` some more

Comment: Something else to note. Things can get messed up as well if you don't have a proper mutex or critical section around operations involving `x`. Since both thread share the same `x` you have to make sure you have some arbitration between the threads so they don't access `x` simultaneously.

Comment: One last question. When you say jumbled do you mean 2000000 prints before 1000000 sometimes and sometimes 1000000 prints before 2000000?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by jumbled! And you answered my 1st question with the printf explanation :)

Comment: The printf C runtime call will make OS API calls to output the string/chars, ie. a kernel call/interrupt.  Once the kernel gets entered, it may reschedule the set of running threads.  It's scheduing and optimization strategy may result in thread2 getting the stdio lock before thread1, so the output gets 'jumbled'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give some sample code that demonstrates the scenario as described, with the exception that I'll eliminate the difference because of the time between the loop ending and printf printing. I'll use a temporary local variable for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t x_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int x = 0;

void *
task_function(void *ptr)
{
    int index;
    int last = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < 1000000; index++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&x_mutex);
        last = ++x;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&x_mutex);
    }

    /* Use last since it won't matter how much time elapses
     * after the loop ends and when the printf is done */
    printf("x = %d\n", last);

}

int
main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int retval1, retval2;

    /* Create two independent threads which will each execute task_function */
    retval1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, task_function, NULL);
    retval2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, task_function, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}
```

If you run this code the last thread to finish should always print 2,000,000 . If it doesn't there is a serious bug. However the first one to finish will print a value that really won't be deterministic unless you knew precisely how the scheduler divided up the tasks and how fast each thread ran.

To drive the point home. Let us say the loop was `5` instead of 1000000. And let us say the threads ran simultaneously at the same speed and that each increment was interlaced. So thread 0 increments first and increments `x` to 1. Thread 2 increments and it is now `2`. eventually if this pattern repeats Thread 1 will be the first to do its loop 5 times and it will see a value of `9`. Thread 2 will then finish it off and display the value of `10`. As you can see depending on how things get scheduled both values could in theory get close if the work were evenly divided. So in this example instead of printing `5` and `10` it printed `9` and `10`.

Without proper mutexes/critical sections/atomic operations related to `x` the code may not even display 2000000. That is because the updates of `x` from both threads could clobber one another producing values of `x` that are not correct. If one took out the mutexes in the `task_function` you'll probably find the results will be pretty flakey.